# MyBB getting user session for chat

Tags: php, cookies, forum, chatroom, mybb

I'm trying to implement a Chat Room for a forum of mine. I built the Chatroom myself using PHP and Ajax, but I'm also trying to figure out how to only allow users that are part of my MyBB forum to use the Chat.

So what I'm basically trying to do is:

- List users in chatroom
- Only allow users that are logged in to Chat

I have no idea how to do this. I'm assuming I have to edit the cookies that MyBB stores. But the [MyBB wiki](http://wiki.mybb.com/index.php/Cookies) doesn't give much information out but what is stored in the cookie.

I'm a bit new to PHP and I'm wondering how to start on this, so I'm wondering what do I need to do to get this to work the way I want?

Comment: `mybbuser This cookie stores the login information for the Frontend, and is set when a user logs in, and is removed when the user logs out. The UID and the login key are stored in this cookie. ` As for list users in the chatroom, that depends on your chatroom code I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include MyBB's global.php file. It will do all work for you.

Then you can use `$mybb->user` array to get any information about the current user.

```
$isLoggedIn = ($mybb->user['uid'] > 0);
```